# Docker container can ping host machine by hostname but not other machines on the same network

Tags: docker

I am experiencing a strange problem when trying to access the machines on my local network from within a docker container. According to some posts on the internet I added a dns entry (default gateway found by ipconfig) in my docker's `daemon.json` file.

When I run a simple container I can ping `google.com` and can easily ping my host machine via its hostname: say `server1`. But strangely enough I cant ping any other machines on the same network: say `server2`, `server3`, etc.

I have made sure that from outside the container all machines are reachable and from inside the container the machines are reachable via their IP addresses except the host machine which is also accessible via hostname. Inside my docker container's `/etc/resolv.conf` I can see the nameserver entry points to my DNS entry in `daemon.json`.

UPDATE:Furthermore the same setup sometimes work and sometimes dont i.e. after trying it after-some time i can get my docker container to access the machines on my local network by their host names .Now even more baffled by this can someone explain or have experienced the same issue in docker desktop for windows.following is the version of docker-desktop

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.2
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.8
Git commit:        6247962
Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
 Version:          18.09.2
 API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:       go1.10.6
 Git commit:       6247962
 Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
 OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
 Experimental:     false
```

Comment: I weep for your brave step into the curious world of Docker on Windows. 

Same thing happened to me, it simply stopped working after some time while it was all and well. Furthermore, my windows ceased to stop reaching the containers via hostnames, I have no clue what I did (if any) on Network. I resetted adapter, reinstalled Docker, etc. to no avail.

What is your Windows version? Make sure it is up to date.

Comment: Version 1803 windows 10 if it is of any use :-)

Comment: I know it is a VERY long shot but i think the most current is 1809. You might want to try upgrading to that. At some point it will force you anyway.

Also are server1, server2 VMs? Windows has some nasty networking issues, especially on VMs.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş no server 1 and server 2 are definitely not vm's